# How to prevent recursive call of update and value change callbacks in knockout.js custom binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, knockout.js

I need to make a custom binding like `value` binding. Here's my code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myValue= {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).change(function() {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value($(this).val());
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        $(element).val(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value))
    }
};
```

Now if I change the observable's value, `update` will be called and the element's value will be changed, so the `change` callback described in `init` will be executed.
It will change the `value` and so the `update` callback will be called and so on. Am I right?

If yes, how can I prevent this recursion?
If not, why?

Comment: Did you try your binding? `update` will be called, but just setting the value of an element with `.val` is not going to trigger the `.change` event. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, are you sure? write as an answer, if you're sure. No I haven't tried :)

Comment: [Check out this example](http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/13/). There's no infinite recursion occurring.

Comment: Thanks, write this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should not result in a recursive situation; The `.val` method won't trigger the `.change` event.

Check out an example using your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/13/